# Need to customize OOTB '/search' PLP API (GET to POST) in Spartacus 4.3

Tags: angular12, spartacus-storefront

We are trying to hit the search api with custom query param but the length of query param is too long, /search api is failing because it is a GET call.

How we can customize the OOTB /search (GET) API into a POST call with custom payload and use all existing functionalities coming from /search API in Spartacus 4.3.

We tried updating the ProductsSearchEffect to our custom Effect by using useClass and writting the custom service for search as POST method but code is not reading our custom Effect and it is still reading OOTB ProductsSearchEffect.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the communication with the backend Search endpoint (e.g. to use `POST` http method, or to use a different endpoint URL, whatever...), by extending the class `OccProductSearchAdapter` and overwriting it's method `search()`. See the followin example:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CustomOccProductSearchAdapter extends OccProductSearchAdapter {
   override search( /* ... */) {
      /* ... */
      return this.http.post( /* ... */ );
   }
}
```

```js
{
   provide: ProductSearchAdapter
   useExisting: CustomOccProductSearchAdapter
}
```

For reference, see the [default implementation of `OccProductSearchAdapter`](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/299caf781cf91955b93c267e44bd953fa5c7ace0/projects/core/src/occ/adapters/product/occ-product-search.adapter.ts#L38-L49).